# EXCEL VBA - data validation

Tags: excel

This is my code for the data validation from cell A7 to any used cell after cell a7.however, error pops up all the time. can anyone help fix it?

```
`Public Sub adjinput()
arr = Sheets("INPUT").[a7].CurrentRegion
With Range(arr).Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, _
 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(A7),A7<>0)"
 .InputTitle = ""
 .ErrorTitle = ""
 .InputMessage = ""
 .ErrorMessage = ""
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

arr will be an array of values, you probably want to use Address - or cut out the middle stage.

```
With Sheets("INPUT").[a7].CurrentRegion.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, _
         AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(A7),A7<>0)"
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
End With
```

Comment: WHERE should i add the address

Comment: but i get the error "9" after i run. it said subscription out of range